# OmniauthCallbacksController endpoint called without callback_phase() being called

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, omniauth

I am using Omniauth for my authentication in a rails project. I have a strategy file called click.rb with a callback_phase method defined. However, I am not seeing the callback phase being initiated in the server log. Rather when the request *GET "/owners/auth/click/callback?code=[FILTERED]* comes through, the callback_phase method is skipped and the action OmniauthCallbacksController::click is called. Since the callback_phase was skipped, request.env["omniauth.auth"].extra is nil.

Does anyone know what might be happening here? I'm running in a Docker container if it makes a difference.

Thanks

Comment: Can you please add the relevant code to like your strategy, the controller and the logs from the request? Give us something to go on.